# Undefined Error in Ruby on Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

I am pretty new to Rails and I have stumbled upoun this problem. I'm guessing it's going to be relatively simple to you pros. I have a model named User and this has all the user attributes in it. I also created a model called list and now I want to. I am now trying to call the method create from the user buy doing something like this below (all happening in the console)

```
sample = User.create(#attributes here)
newlist = sample.List.create(#attributes here)
```

i then get this error

```
irb(main):011:0> sample.Lists.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `Lists' for #<User:0x4146750>
```

Below are my model files for User and List

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  firstName          :string(255)
#  middleName         :string(255)
#  lastName           :string(255)
#  email              :string(255)
#  facebookexternalId :integer
#  userType           :integer
#  gender             :string(255)
#  description        :string(255)
#  location           :string(255)
#  image              :string(255)
#  password           :string(255)
#  notificationId     :string(255)
#  disabled           :boolean
#  disabledNotes      :string(255)
#  city               :string(255)
#  country            :string(255)
#  joinDate           :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :firstName, :middleName , :lastName ,:email , :facebookexternalId, :gender , :description, :location , :image , :city, :country, :disabled
   email_regex= /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
   validates :firstName , :presence =>true,
                          :length => {:maximum => 45}
   validates :lastName , :presence =>true,
                          :length => {:maximum => 45}
   validates :email , :presence =>true,
                     :format =>{:with => email_regex},
                     :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
  validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 140}

  has_many :lists
end
```

Lists

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: lists
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  user_Id     :integer
#  active      :boolean
#  type        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  roughList   :boolean
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use list in it's plural form which would be something like,

`sample_user.lists.create` ...

or

`sample_user.lists.new`

like how you named it in the :has_many

Comment: Thanks so much!.. You actually made me realize another mistake I was making. I wasn't applying the foreign key constraint to the ID of the main user table. Thanks again!